# Taxes on the checkout page is calculating / displaying round instead of float

Tags: checkout, tax, tax-rounding

I have an issue at the checkout stage when selecting taxation region/state it displays the rounded value of tax instead of a decimal.

Can someone help to figure out where or what function can be updated for correct output according to this attached photo?!

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was fixed by installing the plugin **Currency Formatter** and setting up the decimal number parameter to 2

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-currency-formatter